# Prove: that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a  group, any  cyclic  subgroup of $G$ is normal in $G$, and $H$ any subgroup of $G$. Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If every cyclic subgroup of $G$ is normal so is every subgroup?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276957/if-every-cyclic-subgroup-of-g-is-normal-so-is-every-subgroup)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty straightforward:
$$
H=\bigcup_{h\in H}\langle h \rangle
$$
(the conclusion is left to the reader ;)